how can i make the pager less extensive when i hace many information
well in my code i have a pager, but when i have many information it become too long so much that I can't go back to the first page, i need make it like a google pager .
i tried to reduce the variable $total_paginas but it didnt work, i saw some videos about this it, i cant found the solution.
<?php

            //paginador

            $sql_register = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT COUNT(*) as total_registro FROM factura WHERE estatus != 10");

            $result_register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_register);

            $total_registro = $result_register['total_registro'];

            $por_pagina = 20;

            if(empty($_GET['pagina'])){

                $pagina = 1;
            }else{

                $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
            }


            $desde = ($pagina-1) * $por_pagina;
            $total_paginas = ceil($total_registro / $por_pagina);



             $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT f.num_factura,f.fecha,f.total_factura,f.cod_cliente,f.estatus,
                                                      u.nombre as vendedor,
                                                      cl.nombre as cliente
                                                     FROM factura f
                                                     INNER JOIN usuario u
                                                     ON f.usuario = u.id_usuario
                                                     INNER JOIN cliente cl
                                                     ON f.cod_cliente = cl.id_cliente 
                                                       WHERE f.estatus != 10 
                                                       ORDER BY f.fecha ASC
                                                       LIMIT $desde,$por_pagina ");
             mysqli_close($conection);

             $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

             if($result > 0){

                while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    if($data['estatus'] == 1){
                        $estado = '<span class="pagada">Pagada</span>';
                    }else{
                        $estado = '<span class="anulada">Anulada</span>';
                    }
                
                ?>

            <tr id="row_<?php echo $data["num_factura"]; ?>">

                <td><?php echo $data["num_factura"];    ?></td>
               <td><?php echo $data["fecha"];    ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["cliente"];     ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data["vendedor"];   ?></td>
                <td class="estado"><?php echo $estado;   ?></td>
                <td class="textright totalfactura"><span>COP.</span><?php  echo $data["total_factura"]; ?></td>
                
             <td>
                    <div class="div_acciones">
                       <div>
                           
                          <button class="btn_view view_factura" type="button" cl="<?php echo $data["cod_cliente"]; ?>" f="<?php echo $data["num_factura"]; ?>"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></button>

                       </div>
                    

                 
                    <div class="div_factura">
                        <button class="btn_anular anular_factura" fac="<?php echo $data["num_factura"]; ?>"><i class="fas fa-ban"></i></button>
                    </div>
                
                                 
            </div>


                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php

                }
             }

            ?>

         </table>

         <div class="paginador">
            <ul>
                <?php   
                  if($pagina != 1){

                ?>
                <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo 1;   ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-backward-fast"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina - 1;      ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-backward"></i></a></li>
                
                <?php
            }
                    for ($i=1; $i <= $total_paginas ; $i++) { 

                        if($i == $pagina){

                            echo '<li class="pageSelected">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                        }else{
                              echo '<li><a href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';

                        }
                        
                        
                    }

                    if($pagina != $total_paginas){

                ?>
                
                <li><a href="?pagina=<?php  echo $pagina + 1;  ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-forward"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="?pagina=<?php  echo $total_paginas;     ?>"><i class="fa-solid fa-forward-fast"></i></a></li>

            <?php }  ?>
            </ul>
         </div>





    </section>
</div>


Are you saying it is showing too many pages? For instance, if you have 1,000,000 rows and you are showing 10 at a time, it would show 100,000 possible pages, and you want to reduce that? Otherwise I'm not too certain what "extensive" means

My guess is that the OP wants pagination with an overflow indicator (like "...") so that not every page number is shown at once. Something like "1.... 50 51 52 ... 100".

Chris háas yeah bro is just like that, i actually have 1000 dates and 45 Pages but the pager is so extensive, how can i do?

Showdev wow i like ir bro how can i do that?

You might find this helpful: Smart pagination algorithm
